I am having trouble using LSTM layers in Tensorflow.Net
I am currently trying to build a model for my project. I have to build a LSTM-CNN neural network for my tensor data. I have read the documents about tensorflow.net however, LSTM layers are not properly covered in my opinion. I am trying to build my model but only in LSTM layers i am having errors. The erro i am getting is: "Unable to find an entry point named 'TF_GetHandleShapeAndType' in DLL 'tensorflow'".
I have tried every possible CUDA and CUDNN compatabile versions ever and also tried different TensorFlow.Keras and TensorFlow.NET versions. I havent figured out what is the possible problem. I am trying to add layers to my model in this format:
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences: true));
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences: true));
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64));

When I change my TensorFlow.Keras version to 0.10.5 and TensorFlow.NET version to 0.100.5 I dont get the previous error but getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

seems to be a problem with the current version. see this thread for more information. The developer on the project actually explains its an issue with native windows gpu on this thread
